# Classic Asp Soap Client IXMLDOMSelection

Tags: soap, asp-classic, client

classic asp code for Soapclient

```vb
dim soapClient ,XMLReader, xmlDoc

Set soapClient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
    soapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
Call soapClient.MSSoapInit("http://www.jiemai.com/services/JieMaiSlService?wsdl")

    soapClient.ConnectorProperty("Timeout") = 90000 '90 seconds
    soapClient.ConnectorProperty("ConnectTimeout") = 90000 '90 seconds

Set result = soapClient.getAllCategories("1056aed3-eee8-409a-8be0-6dc65962686e", "1.0")


'REsponse.write Result(0)

Response.Write( TypeName( Result ) & "<br/>" & vbCrLf )
```

I am using the above code but i am getting 'IXMLDOMSelection' only that response can anyone please help me

Comment: You're writing out the typename and it looks like that's what it's giving you. Maybe you're expecting `Response.Write(result)`

Comment: When i put  Response.Write(result), i was getting Response object error 'ASP 0185 : 8002000e'

Missing Default Property

/a.asp, line 0

A default property was not found for the object.

Comment: Kevin Thanks for your reply but still i am struggling can you help me please

Answer (score 2):

As you can see you have an **[IXMLDOMSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** object. It is an iterable collection, so you can iterate or use `Response.Write(result.context.xml)` if you want only selection context, this will returns xml of tree.

Comment: Please flag this as the answer.